# GetComputerNameW causes buffer overflow in Windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10

I've been searching around the internet about this issue and it seems really strange to me.
In my program i am getting the name of the computer by the following code:

```
TCHAR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];

memset( ComputerName, 0, sizeof( ComputerName ) );

DWORD dwNameLenght = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH;

GetComputerNameW(ComputerName, &dwNameLenght);
```

I've tested it with a computer name(`ÆÆØ`) that contains unicode characters and it works fine(although `GetLastError()` returns code of 203).
If the name is `DESKTOP-IVHSIQD` no computer name is obtained and `GetLastError()` returns 111, which is said to be buffer overflow.
The operating system is Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Is UNICODE defined? And for that matter, if you're going to use dispense with the macros and use `GetComputerNameW` directly, why use `TCHAR` instead of `wchar_t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your buffer is indeed too small... The documentation on `GetComputerNameW` states:

> lpnSize [in, out] - On input, specifies the size of the buffer, in TCHARs. On output, the number of TCHARs copied to the destination buffer, not including the terminating null character.
>   The lpnSize parameter specifies the size of the buffer required, **including the terminating null character.**

To me that implies that both the buffer itself, and its size in `lpnSize` should be enough to hold the longest possible computer name and the trailing `\0`.

Your buffer is of `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1` size (which is fine according to the documentation), but the value of `dwNameLenght` is 1 character less. `DESKTOP-IVHSIQD` also seems to be exactly `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` long (15 characters), so I would say the overflow happens when the `\0` is being appended to the buffer. Setting `dwNameLenght` to `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1` might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the issue. Seems that i need to be really careful with the documentation :)

Comment: @AlexanderDemerdzhiev: Indeed you have to be careful. When Windows tells you to pass the length of the buffer, you should not pass the length-1.